# Connecting to wireless USB adapter - Puppy Linux Wary

Tags: network-interface, wlan, puppy-linux

Trying to connect to my WLAN on an Acer Travelmate 2301LM. System installed is a Puppy Linux Wary 5.3.

Since it doesn't have an internal adapter, I'm trying to integrate a Netgear N300 WLAN-USB-Mini-Adaptor - precisely a WNA3100M.

The Puppy Internet Connection Wizard doesn't list the wireless device.

If I plug it into my Ubuntu desktop and run `lsusb`, it reads

```
[..]
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0846:9021 NetGear, Inc.
```

`lsusb -v` reveals

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0846:9021 NetGear, Inc. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0846 NetGear, Inc.
  idProduct          0x9021 
  bcdDevice            2.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           46
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           4
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
```

How can I get it to connect?

Comment: Mhmm, trying to identify the chipset on this usb-stick.  I've got the windows install-cd here, but it won't let me extract the `.sys` or `.inf` files.

If I try to extract them through command line zip `7za l Setup.exe` it outputs ...

`7-Zip (A) [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,2 CPUs)
Error: Setup-driver.exe: Can not open file as archive`

Comment: Ok, my suggestion is to stay away from this WLAN USB-Adaptor. It doesn't get detected by Ubuntu 13.10. (it detects something but one can't connect to wlan) and it DEFINATELY does not get detected by Puppy Linux Wary which uses an older kernel.  Bottom line: I'll return it so then can throw it at some windows user.

Comment: As a suggestion for Puppy Linux Wary 5.3.  I am now going with a "ZyXEL ZyAIR G-220 V.2 USB Stick".  It's ancient and ugly but it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your device is not defined on http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Devices/USB I also don't see what driver is needed for the chipset. I assume you can use `wext` driver since it is a generic one, but you need to load the module by `modprobe` if you don't see the driver on `lsmod`. But before it, you need to be able to see if the device is working, you can see it by `iwconfig` if you have the interface. If iwconfig does not output the wifi interface,then you need to verify if you have the correct firmware (`.fw` extension) which is located on `/lib/firmware`.

I think you would save a lot time by selecting any device defined on  http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Devices/USB Atheros chipset is the best in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you, Sven. I will try to identify the chipset and if that doesn't work ... order one from the defined devices.

I know that **Ubuntu 13.10. detected the chipset as a Realtek**.  But that was a friends computer and my Ubuntu 12.10. on the other machine didn't detect it.  Once I have the chipset I'll post it here.

Comment: Sorry, my bad Ubuntu 13.10. did not detect the USB Device (and it is NOT a Realtek). The wireless device that was detected was the one onboard in first place.